# Ingore word and put underscore on each word Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

I just need to find and replace the following word set in VsCode

```
t("US.TL.PACKAGES:installmentDetail.discount")
```

I was tried a lot by following

```
(?:US\.TL\.PACKAGES:)([a-z])([A-Z])
```

but when I used

```
([a-z])([A-Z])
```

this captures all upper in the string.

I need to group by each new word.

```
installment Detail discount
```

To put underscore i'm using

```
\1_\2 in Replace
```

Final output

```
US.TL.PACKAGES:INSTALLMENT_DETAILS.DISCOUNT
```

Comment: So you want to insert underscores in between lower and upper letters in a non-whitespace chunk after `US.TL.PACKAGES:`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew exactly

Comment: @JvdV updated it

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this doesnt seems ignore US.TL.packages `(?:US\.TL\.PACKAGES\:)([a-z])([A-Z])`

Comment: So, you want to use `(?<=\bUS\.TL\.PACKAGES:\S*?[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` and replace with `_`? Please turn on `Aa` option to make  the regex matching case sensitive

Comment: lookbehind is not fixed length - error @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Really? Are you sure you are using the regex in the Visual Studio Code?

Comment: yes i'm.  it says above @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225543/discussion-between-underscore-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: Then you are using Find/Replace in files and not in the Find&Replace window. Then, there is no solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is that two different ?

Comment: Yes, they use different regex libraries.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in window it converts to `t("US.TL.PACKAGES:i\1_\2n\1_\2s\1_\2t\1_\2a\1_\2l\1_\2l\1_\2m\1_\2e\1_\2n\1_\2t\1_\2D\1_\2e\1_\2t\1_\2a\1_\2i\1_\2l.d\1_\2i\1_\2s\1_\2c\1_\2o\1_\2u\1_\2n\1_\2t")`

Comment: i used `\1_\2` there

Comment: Why use `\1` or `\2`? Did you read my comment? *use `(?<=\bUS\.TL\.PACKAGES:\S*?[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` and replace with `_`? Please turn on `Aa` option to make the regex matching case sensitive*

Comment: it does to `t("US.TL.PACKAGES:i_n_s_t_a_l_l_m_e_n_t_D_e_t_a_i_l.d_i_s_c_o_u_n_t")`

Comment: Did you make the pattern case sensitive? You did not.

Comment: yes i didn't. it works then also i need to Upser case that entire word. how do i ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew like in question Final Output

Comment: After the first replacement, use `(?<=\bUS\.TL\.PACKAGES:\S*?)[A-Za-z]+` and replace with `\U$0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following can be used in the Search & Replace tool, not in the Find/Replace in Files feature (opened with <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F</kbd>) because the latter uses another, old regex engine and the former uses the modern ECMAScript 2018+ compliant engine as in most major JavaScript environments:

1. Insert an underscore between each lower- and uppercase letter in a non-whitespace streak of text after a `US.TL.PACKAGES:` string:

```js
(?<=\bUS\.TL\.PACKAGES:\S*?[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

Replace with a mere `_`. *Make sure the `Aa` option is checked* as matching must be case sensitive:

[image]

2. Make all streaks of letters in a non-whitespace streak of text after a `US.TL.PACKAGES:` string uppercase:

```js
(?<=\bUS\.TL\.PACKAGES:\S*?)[A-Za-z]+
```

Replace with `\U$0`.

[image]

and the result is

[image]